# Declaring multiple maintainers for an extension?

Tags: extension

Can I declare more than one author/maintainer in an extension's info.xml file? Maintenance of one of our public extensions fell to me a while ago as the other dev who wrote it left, but I don't want to remove his name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer is no :-(

I just recently added two names between the author tags in the info.xml for a new extension - looks ok on Github!

Not sure if the CiviCRM automated listing will choke on it...